# How to clear BLOB created at the time of HTML5 FileReader calls

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, filereader

I am seeing BLOBs created at the time of reading JPEG image file from local system through **FilreReader** using **readAsDataURL** API are not cleared out from memory in mobile Safari till page reload.

I have tried clearing objects by setting to null and clearing all the references.

```
var reader = new FileReader(); 
reader.onloadend  = function(event) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = this.value;
   ....
}
reader.readAsDataURL(referanceToFile);
```

When try to submit large images browser is crashing consistently.  Please share your thoughts and suggestions if anyone experienced same or similar issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The method `readAsDataURL()` doesn't create any blobs but so called DataURIs.

To clear a DataURI you just have to set the `src` attribute which references the DataURI to something different or to an emtpy string:

```
img.src = '';
```

Indeed, the method `readAsDataURL()` reads FROM blobs, but this shouldn't cause any issues with the blobs if your set them to null.

**See also:**

- [Delete Javascript blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899333/delete-javascript-blobs)
- [When are JavaScript Blob objects garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206823/when-are-javascript-blob-objects-garbage-collected)